# Android Push Notifications stop working after migration

Tags: java, android, notifications

Android Push Notifications stop working after migration SDK27 to SDK28/SDK29.Has something changed? No more notifications are received on the phone, no data or notification.

The phone generates a Token and it seems everything is OK, but there are no Notifications.
This PHP code working with SDK27.

```
$msgData = array (
        'mtext' => $body,
        'mtitle' => $title,
        'mtype' => $messageType
        );
    $fields = array
            (
                'registration_ids'      => $registrationIds,
                'priority' => 'high',
                'data' => $msgData
            );
```

I try to add my channel         'android_channel_id' => 'xxx_channel_id_01',
No luck.

The internal notification works if I run a notification from the code.

I'm trying to receive a notification:

```
public class xxxFirebaseMsgService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {

@Override
public void onNewToken(String Token) {
```

Any ideas where I'm going to look for the problem?

Comment: did you solve this?

Comment: Yes, not all libraries had been upgraded.